# why it shows me error while I am creating envelope using Docusign apis?

Tags: docusignapi

```
Client error: `POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/74724935-eef9-4006-a4be-05c65feb49fc/envelopes` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:
```

{"errorCode":"PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED","message":"The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide your code or any information at all about how you are making the API call.
But this error means you didn't set Auth correctly.
You need to provide a security header with your token that has not expired and is valid for this environment.
Suggest you read how to [use OAuth with DocuSign](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/).

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things you can check listed here: https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-from-the-trenches-may-2020

- Is your integration key live?
- Can you make calls in the Demo environment successfully?
- How is your x-docusign-authentication header defined? *Please don't provide sensitive info like your password or your the key itself, just the format with the key credentials replaced with generic text*
- Are you using an SDK or calling the API directly?

Comment: - I have a free developer account.
- Yes, I can call APIs in postman with a demo environment
- I just pass auth token and content type in the header
- I am calling APIs not SDK with

Comment: It sounds like your auth header isn't set up correctly. If your token is `xxxyyyzzz` the format for the header should be `Authorization: Bearer xxxyyyzzz` - is that what you have?